# Get first/last value from SQL selection using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I have a SQL query in my php file (I use this file to calculate graphic timeblocks based on starting time and duration of an event; starttime and duration are my columns in SQL table).

How can I print/get last or first value from selection below using php? I mean first or last value from column 'starttime' to be precise.

```
$query1=mysqli_query($db,"select * from LISTS where category='planner' 
order by date,timestart asc");
```

I googled since I am very much beginner but results did not make much sense because I don't have much skills yet. Therefore I am asking you.

Thanks in advance. Also can you please explain in very primitive way, some terms I might not understand at this point.

Comment: `(select * from LISTS where category='planner' 
order by date,timestart asc limit 1) union (select * from LISTS where category='planner' 
order by date,timestart desc limit 1)`

Comment: @splash58 Thanks but I dont want any union, I just want to be able to get and display on page first or last, lets say I WANT FIRST ONLY starttime value printed on page. I have problem to make the echo statement work. I have the querry, I just do not know how to apply echo on it so it would get it and print it. Hope the question is clear now.

Comment: If dataset is not huge, get all query result to array, and test the last pass of a  loop

Comment: read here - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php I think you will write the code by yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't both the first and last value in one MySql state you can use "Union". The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

To get either first or last value use "limit" and set this to 1, then order by asc or desc.

Example:

```
select * from LISTS where category='planner' order by date,timestart asc 
limit 1) union (select * from LISTS where category='planner' order by 
date, timestart desc limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks @MatMat but I dont want any union, I just want to be able to get and display on page first or last, lets say I WANT FIRST ONLY starttime value printed on page.  I have problem to make the echo statement work. I have the querry, I just do not know how to apply echo on it so it would get it and print it. Hope the question is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to find only first value based on my selection.  I had to show it on the page, this is what worked for me.

```
$query3=mysqli_query($db,"select datetime from LISTS where
category='planner' order by date,timestart asc");

$SelectionArray=mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
$FIRSTdatetime=reset($SelectionArray);
echo $FIRSTdatetime;
```